# C++ lambdas in Visual Studio 2013: capturing this pointer

Tags: visual-studio, c++11

Looks like if lambda is defined inside a member function and *this* is captured then inside lambda all class members can be accesses without using *this* keyword, that is I can do

```
some_class_field = ....
```

instead of

```
this->some_class_field = ....
```

Is it portable behavior or specific to Visual Studio?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is expected :

§ 5.1.2 paragraph 7

The lambda-expression’s compound-statement yields the function-body (8.4) of the function call operator,
but for purposes of name lookup (3.4), determining the type and value of this (9.3.2) and transforming idexpressions
referring to non-static class members into class member access expressions using (*this) (9.3.1),
the compound-statement is considered in the context of the lambda-expression. [ Example:

```
struct S1 {
    int x, y;
    int operator()(int);
    void f() {
        [=]()->int {
            return operator()(this->x + y); // equivalent to S1::operator()(this->x + (*this).y)
        // this has type S1*
        };
    }
};
```